# QML gradients with an orientation

Tags: qt, gradient, qml, qt-quick

QML gradient allows only from top to bottom in a Rectangle. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qml-gradient.html) says that 
it has to be done through combination of rotation and clipping.

I have just started learning QML (and little experience with HTML/CSS). Here is my code which I think can be improved for a lot better:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400; height: 400;

    Rectangle {
    width: 567; height: 567;

    gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
        position: 0.0;
        color: "white";
        }
            GradientStop {
        position: 1.0;
        color: "blue";
        }
    }
    x: 116.5;
    transformOrigin: Item.Top;
    rotation: 45.0;
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest what are the better ways to do this?

Answer (score 10):

I've solve this probling with the following code: https://code.google.com/p/ytd-meego/source/browse/trunk/playground/FeedBook/qmltube/HorizontalGradient.qml?r=144

Here is what I've done using the example of NielsMayer:

```
    Rectangle {
        width: parent.height
        height: parent.width
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        rotation: 90

        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "black" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "white" }
        }
    }
```

And this is working well. Have fun !

Comment: Indeed awesome trick, works like a charm! I did the same, however forgot adding anchor - lead to some uncovered stripes.

Comment: I don't understand, how does this work for you? If you *ROTATE* the *Child* Rectangle, then it will go outside of the *Parent* Rectangle. And this works exactly as I stated for me:
http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/17/0802/h_1501648599_3384672_6ac0b27d3e.png

It's a non-robust trick. It doesn't work in All cases like LinearGradient does.

Comment: @general656 maybe you missed the trick : you must swap height and width of the parent in the child, it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 8):

The Qt Graphical Effects module introduced in Qt 5.1 provides three gradient types.
With the `LinearGradient` item (effect) it is no longer necessary to apply rotation in order to achieve e.g. a horizontal color gradient.
In particular by means of the `start` and `end` point (attributes) of `LinearGradient` **any** gradient direction is possible.

The following code implements a 45° angle (as proposed in the original post) by starting top right with white and ending bottom left with black:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    id:myItem
    width: 300
    height: 300

    LinearGradient {
        anchors.fill: parent
        start: Qt.point(myItem.width, 0)
        end: Qt.point(0, myItem.height)
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "white" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "black" }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the documentation is correct.
The only other way I can think of is to write a custom QML component in C++ which does what you want.

If you have Qt/C++ knowledge you could start here:

- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-extending.html
- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarative-tutorials-extending-chapter1-basics.html

The Rectangle could be a good template or base class:

- http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/declarative/graphicsitems/qdeclarativerectangle_p.h

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [orientation property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gradient.html#orientation-prop) from **Qt 5.12**